# iOS: What is the best way to test internet connection through out the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to test internet connection if it is availiable. Only problem is I want to test it through out the app, so no matter what viewcontroller I am on if I lose connection I can tell. I already have a way to test connection, just need a way to do it throughout the app.

Comment: Search on "Reachability".

Answer (score 2):

[`Reachability`](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) is a good open source little tool for monitoring an iOS device's network state, it can provide notifications when the network state changes too. You could use `Reachability` in your app delegate or a global singleton for eg. - so it's accessible from everywhere in your app.